# How to dock an electron application at the top of my screen

Tags: javascript, electron

I am working on an electron application and what i would like to do, is ensure that other applications/web browsers are automatically docked beneath the electron app and aren’t hidden behind the toolbar when maximized.

Can anyone help? any help would be much appreciated!

Below is the code i have so far in my index.js:

```
function createWindow(){
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({height: 10, width: 300, frame: false,titleBarStyle: 'none',resizable: false, webPreferences: { nodeIntegration: true, 
  contextIsolation: false }})

mainWindow.setAlwaysOnTop(true, 'screen-saver') 
mainWindow.setVisibleOnAllWorkspaces(true);
mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')
mainWindow.setMenuBarVisibility(false)
mainWindow.setPosition(0,0)


app.on('ready', () => {
createWindow();
})
```

Comment: What toolbar do you mean? Btw contextIsolation: false is a heavy security flaw. Consider doing it right and use a bridge https://www.electronjs.org/de/docs/latest/tutorial/context-isolation

Comment: @SirOneOfMany thanks, I'll look into that!....I'm currently working on a toolbar application which is placed at the top of the screen. The problem I'm having is when i open up a browser, it hides behind the toolbar app which is not what i want. I want the browser to be docked beneath the toolbar app.